# How to faster wordpress ajax in frontend?

Tags: wordpress

WP tends to load a lot of things with ajax admin, but what I need is to only load it to use basic ajax with my own calls and functions.

[This posts says](https://coderwall.com/p/of7y2q/faster-ajax-for-wordpress):

```
<?php
//mimic the actuall admin-ajax
define('DOING_AJAX', true);

if (!isset( $_POST['action']))
    die('-1');

//make sure you update this line 
//to the relative location of the wp-load.php
require_once('../../../../../wp-load.php'); 

//Typical headers
header('Content-Type: text/html');
send_nosniff_header();

//Disable caching
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
header('Pragma: no-cache');


$action = esc_attr(trim($_POST['action']));

//A bit of security
$allowed_actions = array(
    'my_allow_action_1',
    'my_allow_action_2',
    'my_allow_action_3',
    'my_allow_action_4',
    'my_allow_action_5'
);

if(in_array($action, $allowed_actions)){
    if(is_user_logged_in())
        do_action('MY_AJAX_HANDLER_'.$action);
    else
        do_action('MY_AJAX_HANDLER_nopriv_'.$action);
}
else{
    die('-1');
}
```

And it says:

```
Next we Only need to hook our callbacks to this handler like so:

//For logged in users
add_action('MY_AJAX_HANDLER_{$action_name}','function_callback_name');
//For logged out users
add_action('MY_AJAX_HANDLER_nopriv_{$action_name}','function_callback_name');
```

Finally says :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var data={
         action:'action_name',
         otherData: 'otherValue'
    };
    $.post('http://url/to/your/MY_CUSTOM_AJAX.php', data, function(response){
         alert(response);
    });
});
```

But I got confused, as I don't know what it means with SOME CUSTOM TEXT or how it is handling the variables etc, this is how I currently do:

**function.php**

```
  add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_data_fetch', 'data_fetch' );
  add_action('wp_ajax_data_fetch' , 'data_fetch');

  function data_fetch(){
    $dates = $_POST['dates'];
    $dates = explode(',', $dates);
    $args = array(
      'meta_query' => array(
        array(
          'key' => 'anno',
          'value' => array($dates[0], $dates[1]),
          'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
          'no_found_rows' => true, 
          'update_post_meta_cache' => false, 
          'update_post_term_cache' => false, 
          'type' => 'NUMERIC'
        ),
      )
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if( $query->have_posts() ): 
      $coordinates = [];
      $links = [];
      while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
        $id = get_the_ID();
        $location = get_field('location');
        $lat = $location['lat'];
        $lng = $location['lng'];
        $title = get_the_title($id);
        if ( ! add_post_meta( $id, 'latitude', $lat, true) ) {
          delete_post_meta($id, 'latitude');
          update_post_meta($id, 'latitude', $lat, true);
        }
        if ( ! add_post_meta( $id, 'longitude', $lng, true) ) {
          delete_post_meta($id, 'longitude');
          update_post_meta($id, 'longitude', $lng, true);
        }
        $latitude = get_field('latitude');
        $longitude = get_field('longitude');
        $coordinates[] = $latitude.", ".$longitude;
        $links[] = get_permalink();
        $anno = get_field('anno');
        $site[] = get_field("site_name", "option", true);
        $contentProprierty[] = array("links"=>$links, "coordinates"=>$coordinates, "anno"=>$anno, "ids"=>$id, "site"=>$site, "title"=>$title);
      endwhile;
      echo json_encode($contentProprierty);
      die;
    endif;
    wp_die();
  }
```

**JS** in front end:

```
var ajax_url = '<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>';

$.ajax({
  url : ajax_url,
  type: 'post',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: { 
    action: 'data_fetch', dates: datesSearch 
  },
  success: function(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      coords.push(data[i].coordinates[i]);
      links.push(data[i].links[i]);
      years.push([data[i].anno]);
      ids.push(data[i].ids);
      titles.push(data[i].title);
      currentSite.push("curr");
      site.push(thisSiteName);
    };
  }
});
```

How would I implement the custom ajax in order not to load the whole thing wp does with its own ajax admin?

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action('MY_AJAX_HANDLER_{$action_name}','function_callback_name');
//For logged out users
add_action('MY_AJAX_HANDLER_nopriv_{$action_name}','function_callback_name');
```

These action hooks only call data related to your current ajax function nothing else you can use wp_nonce_field to secure your function from hacking and securing the site. inside the function.

Comment: Thanks, would you be able for future users too on here, to create a real example code using the function provided in my question?

Comment: Yes, I am able to create a real example using your code.

Comment: Please can you the example then?